# Is it possible to embed nginx in a C/C++ application

Tags: c++, c, nginx, embedding

The application runs in Linux, Windows, Macintosh.

Also, if yes, how much effort is required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does nginx run on windows?

I think you'd have a much better result using an existing library that includes a good http server.  My first choice would be [libevent](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/).

Answer (score 2):

Windows version of Ngnix isn't open sourced due to low quality of source code; it's just for testing/development.

For Linux and *BSD, you can embed your C/C++ application into Nginx by using [module API](http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html). But if you want to stay in your application, [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) and [libeio](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libeio.html) is your friend.